# Grafana variable with AND

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, grafana

I've created the following variable in Grafana:

```
{"find": "terms", "field": "is_acr.keyword"}
```

It returns `3,4,8`

Actually I have to add an AND clause to that variable, the result is expected to be something like

```
{"find": "terms", "field": "is_acr.keyword" AND "ip_code.keyword": "AM"}
```

but Grafana returns

`Template variables could not be initialized: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 54`

Comment: Please show how you added/defined that variable in Grafana. Also the error is pretty clear -> `... AND ..` is not a valid json.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly and "AND" but this should do what you're looking for

```
{"find": "terms", "field": "is_acr.keyword" , "query": "ip_code.keyword: AM"}
```